# Testing models with RSpec using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am using devise for authentication in my rails app and I'm unable to test any model with RSpec. Controller specs work fine, but I'm unable to make model specs work.

I am getting this error:

```
Failures:

1) Group should create new group

Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:25:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-rails-2.5.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:29:in `run_in'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:64:in `block in run_all'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:64:in `each'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:64:in `run_all'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:110:in `run_hook'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:191:in `block in eval_before_eachs'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:191:in `each'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:191:in `eval_before_eachs'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:144:in `run_before_each'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:106:in `with_around_hooks'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:46:in `block in run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:99:in `block in with_pending_capture'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:98:in `catch'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:98:in `with_pending_capture'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:45:in `run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:262:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:258:in `map'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:258:in `run_examples'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `map'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `block in run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:12:in `report'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
 # /home/hrvoje/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I have included

```
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers
```

in my spec_helper.rb. 
Here is my model test file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Group do

  before :each do 
    @group = Factory.build(:group)
  end 

  it "should create new group" do
    Group.create!(@group)
  end
end
```

This is my factories.rb file

```
Factory.define :group do |group|
  group.name "Example group"
  group.description "Example description"
end
```

How to fix this?

Comment: that's the whole error? no line number?

Comment: yeah, no line number. I can put stack trace if it helps...

Comment: Yes, please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: why arey ou creating a group again when you've already created a factory of the group? should it be @group.should_not be_nil instead of Group.create!

Comment: I think factory doesn't create anything. It just defines attributes. Anyways, it doesn't work with @group.should_not be_nil either. Throwing the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```