# rspec integration test with devise throws NoMethodError error

Tags: rspec, devise, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a similar error posted here, but all will not fix my problem.

My file 'spec/request/news_controller_spec.rb' looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "NewsController" do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  describe "GET /news" do

    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      @user.confirm!
      sign_in @user
    end

    it "after login should show the latest news an screen" do
      page.should have_content("News")
    end
  end
end
```

If I run the test I'll get:

```
Failures:

  1) Campaigns GET /news works!
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
     # /Users/.../gems/devise-1.5.3/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:25:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-rails-2.8.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:35:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:35:in `run_in'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in `block in run_all'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in `each'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in `run_all'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:368:in `run_hook'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:292:in `block in run_before_each_hooks'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:292:in `each'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:292:in `run_before_each_hooks'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:217:in `run_before_each'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:79:in `block in run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:173:in `with_around_hooks'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:77:in `run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:355:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:351:in `map'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:351:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:337:in `run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:338:in `block in run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:338:in `map'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:338:in `run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
     # /Users/.../gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I followed instructions on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29 and other similar Questions here, but I can't find a solution.

I'm using following gemset:

- capybara (1.1.2)
- devise (1.5.3)
- factory_girl_rails (1.6.0)
- rails (3.2.0, 3.1.1)
- rspec (2.8.0)
- rspec-core (2.8.0)
- rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
- rspec-rails (2.8.1)

and some other gems.

Can anybody help me, getting my integration tests with a logged in user get running. In this case the news are only displayed, if a user is logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mixed up `Test::Unit` and `RSpec` configurations? *As of rspec-rails-2.0.0 and devise-1.1, the best way to put devise in your specs is simply to add the following into spec_helper:* https://gist.github.com/1682113

Comment: I hope so. I have a file _spec/support/devise.rb_ and in this file I had written the `RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end`. The files in the support-directory should be included by `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}`. Right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725169/testing-models-with-rspec-using-devise You definitely forgot `:type => :controller` part. Just removed it and got same error.

Comment: I got the same error. It does no matter using `:type => :controller`.

Comment: I got the same error after upgrading to rspec, seems an rspec API changes?

Answer (score 9):

I actually had the same exact problem, and after googling a little bit I found that including `Warden::Test::Helpers` directly was a more concise solution for request specs, since it programmatically signs in/out users just like this:

```
# spec/support/request_helpers.rb
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers

module RequestHelpers
  def create_logged_in_user
    user = Factory(:user)
    login(user)
    user
  end

  def login(user)
    login_as user, scope: :user
  end
end
```

In short, just include `Warden::Test::Helpers` and then use the `login_as <your_user>` method and that's it!

Solution taken from here: http://simple10.com/rspec-capybara-devise-login-tests/

Comment: Also, take into account that Devise::TestHelpers only work if you describe a controller class like:
describe NewsController ... instead of ... describe "NewsController"