# Rails 4 + Rspec + Devise: undefined method 'env' in controller specs for sign_in a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

In my spec_helper.rb I've added

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

In controller spec before :all hook I'am trying to sign in user with this code

```
 @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
 user = FactoryGirl.create(:confirmed_user)
 sign_in user
```

and get NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try requiring Warden::Test::Helpers.  See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996246/rspec-integration-test-with-devise-throws-nomethoderror-error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've changed `before(:all)` to `before(:each)`, and now it works. Looks like API incompatibility between `devise` (used `github` master branch) and `rspec` 2.14.1.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the `@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]` line if you are writing specs for internal controllers of Devise. Referenced from the test helpers section in the [Devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Answer (score 0):

The controller spec will have a request object in it. You should probably change from @request to request..

```
 request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Answer (score 0):

`@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]` is only needed when you are testing a Devise controller or a controller that inherits from a Devise controller, as stated in the Devise [documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-tests):

> If you are testing **Devise internal controllers or a controller that inherits from Devise's**, you need to tell Devise which mapping should be used before a request. This is necessary because Devise gets this information from the router, but since controller tests do not pass through the router, it needs to be stated explicitly.

If you are not in the case mentioned above you don't need to add it.
If you are in the case mentioned above but `@request` is `nil`, try adding these helpers to your `rails_helper.rb`:

```rb
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
```